# Using Nagios With RKhunter

Tags: nagios, system-monitoring, rkhunter

I have installed rkhunter and would like the rootkit checks to be done automatically with alerts. How would i go about integrating RKhunter with nagios?
One scenario would be if a root kit is found, i would receive a critical alert on nagios else the state is OK.
I also notice that there is this script related to rkhunter, but have no idea how to use it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !

ps : i am able to do less complicated configurations and coding. other than that i need some guidance.

Comment: When i run the ./check_rootkit plugin, i get this error
./check_rootkit: line 25: ./utils.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: You need to run it in the directory where all of your other nagios plugins are.

Comment: Running it in /usr/local/nagios/libexec
I get the following output :
WARNING - rkhunter returned state 1
What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some trial and error, i gave up on rkhunter and move to check_chkrootkit. Also available on nagios exchange.
http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Linux/check_chkrootkit/details